# Fatal error: Class 'Aws\Sdk' not found in /var/www/html/index.php

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-dynamodb

I'm new to AWS & I've set up a LAMP server according to these instructions:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/guide/installation.html

I'm getting "Fatal error: Class 'Aws\Sdk' not found".

I can see the SDK installed here:

/var/www/html/vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php

Is there a cenfiguration file somewhere that needs to know the path?

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<?php
use Aws\SDK;

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);

// Fatal error: Class 'Aws\Sdk' not found here
$sdk = new Aws\Sdk([
    'region'   => 'us-west-2',
    'version'  => 'latest'
]);
?>
```

thank you!

Comment: No, don't know anything about that!

Comment: I'm sorry, I thought this was a completely different question... I don't think my solution will actually do anything for you... My bad!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't an Aws\Sdk class in version 2 of the SDK which that tutorial suggests you install. You don't instantiate the SDK itself, you need to use a specific service. For example, if you were using S3.

```
use Aws\S3\S3Client;

$client = S3Client::factory([
    'region' => 'us-east-1',

    // Credentials etc
]);
```

- [v2 Docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/guide/)

If you do wish to use the version 3 version of the API, change your composer.json file to read

```
"aws/aws-sdk-php": "^3.11"
```

Rather than

```
"aws/aws-sdk-php": "2.*"
```

Then you can use the SDK class to create clients. Although I believe the example above will also still work.

```
$sharedConfig = [
    'region'  => 'us-west-2',
    'version' => 'latest'
];

// Create an SDK class used to share configuration across clients.
$sdk = new Aws\Sdk($sharedConfig);

// Create an Amazon S3 client using the shared configuration data.
$client = $sdk->createS3();
```

- [v3 Docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/guide/getting-started/basic-usage.html)

Comment: Oh, that is very important information.  It's more consistent with what I saw when looking at the sdk source code.  I will look at this again tomorrow.   Thanks a lot!

Comment: So sorry, the company diverted me to work on something else for a few days.  I will be back to this and report back.  I'm expecting you are absolutely correct!   Thank you for your help!

Comment: thank you for your help--got it working!  Merry Christmas too!

Comment: Excellent. Merry Christmas to you too!